# How can I bind a list/collection of strings to the rows of a column in a data grid in WPF?

Tags: c#, list, datagrid

I am new to WPF and data binding. I an trying bind a list of strings to a row on a data grid column, Animals, in WPF. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but the column shows up as blank when I run the solution. To add rows this way instead of using a DataTable and looping through the list and adding the rows because the next column I am adding will be of type Combobox so I didn't wanna implement Ui elements into the DataTable.

```
public List<string> Animals {get; set;} = new List<string>
{
    "Dogs",
    "Cats",
    "Birds"
};



<DataGrid

filtergrid:DataGridExtensions.UseBackgroundWorkerForFiltering="True"
                filtergrid:DataGridExtensions.IsFilterVisible="True"
                filtergrid:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False"
                ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filtergrid:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, 
ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="10,50,0,0"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Animals" Width="Auto" 
Binding="{Binding Animals}" IsReadOnly="True" />                       
                </DataGrid.Columns> 
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right but in order to show something I think you need to do a selection.

So you could bind a property to SelectedIndex which is set to 0 or whatever you like.